# How to display/get the column 2 value from database not display in select option?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table query which is displayed thru select option. The column 1 value is displayed on it. When I select the row 1 value from column 1, I also want the value on column 2 automatically displayed, how would I code that?

Example : medicinename(column1) = medicineprice(column2)

The `medicinename` is in select option. The `medicineprice` is not. Just want to display automatically the price every time I select the `medicinename`.

```
<div class="col-md-3"><label><h5>Medicine Name : </h5>
<select name="selectmedicine" class="form-control col-sm-4" id="medicinename" style="width:200px">
    <option id="0" style="width:100px"> Select here...</option>
        <?php
            require_once 'config.php';
            $medicine = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medicine");
            while ($displaymedicine = mysql_fetch_array($medicine)) {
            $medicineid = $displaymedicine['id'];
            $medicinename = $displaymedicine['medicinename'];
            $medicineprice = $displaymedicine['medicineprice'];
        ?>

        <option id="<?php echo $displaymedicine['medicineid']; ?>"><?php if($displaymedicine ['medicineid'] == $displaymedicine ['medicinename']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?><?php echo $displaymedicine ['medicinename'] ?></option>            

        <?php 
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want another dropdown containing the column2 data i.e. the price?

Comment: Do you mean that when you select the medicine name, price of that medicine should get populated in another dropdown?

Comment: nope, just want to get/dispay the value of column 2 everytime I select column 1 of the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to be returned the price of the medicine to your PHP script when you select the name of the medicine? In which case you need to add a `value=""` attribute to the `<option` tag. It is the contents of `value=""` that is returned to the script i.e. if this option was selected from your `<select name="selectmedicine">`

```
<option value="999"...>Penicillin</option>
```

Then PHP would receive $_POST['selectmedicine'] which would contain `999`

```
<div class="col-md-3"><label><h5>Medicine Name : </h5>
<select name="selectmedicine" class="form-control col-sm-4" id="medicinename" style="width:200px">
    <option id="0" style="width:100px"> Select here...</option>
<?php

    require_once 'config.php';

    $medicine = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medicine");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($medicine)) {
        echo '<option id="' . $row['medicineid']  . '"';
        echo ' value="' . $row['medicineprice'] . '"';
        if($row['medicineid'] == $row['medicinename']) {
           echo ' selected="selected"'; 
        }
        echo '>';
        echo $row['medicinename'];
        echo '</option>'            
    }
?>
</select>
```

Of course a better solution would be to put the unique `ID` of the `medicine` table into the `value=""` attribute. Then when the form is posted to your PHP script you read your database for that one row and you have all the data related to that medicine available to the script.

So that would be

```
<div class="col-md-3"><label><h5>Medicine Name : </h5>

<select name="selectmedicine" class="form-control col-sm-4" id="medicinename" style="width:200px">

    <option id="0" style="width:100px"> Select here...</option>


<?php

    require_once 'config.php';

    $medicine = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medicine");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($medicine)) {
        echo '<option id="' . $row['medicineid']  . '"';

> changed code line
        echo ' value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
> changed code line

        if($row['medicineid'] == $row['medicinename']) {
           echo ' selected="selected"'; 
        }
        echo '>';
        echo $row['medicinename'];
        echo '</option>'            
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you RiggsFolly. with your second option I already got the value of the price on the next page. 

if (isset($_POST['price'])) {

               $getprice = $_POST['price'];
               echo $getprice;
              }
how could i also display the medicinename. with this code i got no return value.

if (isset($_POST['selectmedicine'])) {

               $getmedicinename = $_POST['selectmedicine'];
               echo $getmedicinename;
}

Comment: Which version was what you wanted to do? I admit I was not sure!

Comment: I mean with your second version, I got the price value already but I got no return value on the medicne name if want to display also the selected medicine name.?

if (isset($_POST['selectmedicine'])) { $getmedicinename = $_POST['selectmedicine']; echo $getmedicinename; }

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly. I have change the code line (row id) I now got the point. When i change the id to medicinename. I will be able to display the medicine name. with this code on the next page.
if (isset($_POST['selectmedicine'])) { $getmedicinename = $_POST['selectmedicine']; echo $getmedicinename; }

Comment: same thing when I change the id to medicineprice.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what problem you are having. Maybe edit the question or ask another question specific to this new problem

Comment: now my point is if  I choose the medicineprice on the codeline you pointed.  with this code on the next page--> &_POST['selectmedicine']; I will be able to display the price of the medicine, now I want also to display the medicine name without adding a select option.

Comment: LIke it says in the answer. On the second page you use $_POST['selectedmedicine'] as the key to a simple MYSQL Query like `SELECT * FROM medicine WHERE id = {$_POST['selectedmedicine']}` Then you have ALL the medicine data available and you can use as much or as little of it as you want

Comment: sorry if i confuse you with my question. To summarize my point, when I choose to select the medicine name on the option. I will be able to display the medicine name as well as the medicine price. (only one select option).

Comment: Are you talking about this all happening on a single page and using some javascript to pick the value out of the option and show Name and price some where else on the same page

Comment: no, the madicine name and medicine price will be displayed on the next page. only one select option and in the selection is medicine name only.

Comment: So when you build the second page use the ID to go and get the medicine row again. I know are wangling for me to suggest putting both the Name and the Price into the `value=""` attribute, but it a bad idea so I am not going to suggest anything like that.

Comment: thank you so much RiggsFolly. Now I know how to do it with your idea of MYSQL Query like SELECT * FROM medicine WHERE id = {$_POST['selectedmedicine']} on the next next page. Sorry for Im just a newbie.

Comment: i can now display whatever value on the table. thanks a lot for the idea.